# How to use python (3.8) to fill a form with enctype='multipart/form-data'?

Tags: php, python, html

I'm trying to fill this form

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="upload.php" method="POST">
    <p>Upload your file</p>
    <input type="file" name="uploaded_file"></input><br />
    <input type="text" name="id"></input><br />
    <input type="submit" value="Upload" name="upload"></input>
  </form>
```

with python 3.8 using requests.post() in this way

```
import requests
path = "my\\path\\file.example"
id = str(input("Your id: "))
url = "http://mysite.example/upload.php"
file = {'uploaded_file': open(path, "rb"), 'id': id}
requests.post(url, files=file)
```

but it doesn't work.

If i fill the form manually it works, i also show you the PHP code of upload.php:

```
<?php
    if(!empty($_FILES['uploaded_file'])){

        $id = $_POST['id'];
        $path = "users/".$id."/files/";
        $path = $path . basename( $_FILES['uploaded_file']['name']);

        if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploaded_file']['tmp_name'], $path)){

            echo "The file '".  basename( $_FILES['uploaded_file']['name']).
            "' has been uploaded in path: ".$path."\n";

        }else{
            echo "There was an error uploading the file, please try again!";
        }
    }
?>
```

Where am I doing wrong?

Comment: maybe in PHP add code which display values which you get and then you will see if  there is difference.

Comment: `input()` always gives string so there is no need to use `str()`

Comment: in `files=` you should send only file, not `id`. `id` should be rather in `data=`

Comment: I changed my code in `requests.post(url, files=file, data={'id':id})` and now it works, thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `files=` you should send only `file`, not `id`.

```
files={'upload_file': open(path, "rb")}
```

eventually with some information about this file

```
files={'upload_file': ('foobar.txt', open(text,'rb'), 'text/plain')}
```

`id` should be rather in `data=` (eventually in `json=` or `params=`)

```
data={'id': id}
```

---

**BTW:** In PHP you could add code which display values which you get from client and then you will see if there are differences between data from `form` and data from `requests()`